# check exist script [not working]

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

I want to check the existence of a path directory and included a sample directory where I have permissions to view files and this message comes up:

```
No such file or directory /long_path/path1/abc.txt
No such file or directory /long_path/path2/xyz.txt
```

Here is some code:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
while read line; do
(ls -l $line)
done </something/pathlist.txt
```

Inside pathlist.txt:

```
/long_path/path1/abc.txt
/long_path/path2/xyz.txt
```

I tried various iterations... example2.sh code:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "Start!"
#entry="/something/pathlist.txt"
while read entry; do
    if [ -s $entry ];
    then
        echo "$entry exists"
    else
        echo "$entry does not exist..."
fi
done </something/pathlist.txt
```

example3.sh code:

```
#!/bin/csh
while read entry; do
    if [ -e $entry ];
    then
        echo "$entry does not exist"
    else
        echo "$entry exists "
 fi
 done </something/pathlist.txt
```

**Please Help Me!**

Comment: This is question for https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Use `if [ -e "$entry" ];`

Comment: I'm using a UNIX box, and the code doesn't work. On Solaris the code works fine. smh... [Shake My Head] #stupidpost

Comment: @YuriiKolesnykov Bash questions are on-topic here too ;) However, MasestroCookies, UNIX is not. If you want to ask about that head over to [unix.se]. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two things going on. `if list; then list; [elif list; then list;] ... [else list;] fi` statement operates on exit statuses. If the exit status of list #1 is 0 then list 2 is executed; else it goes to the list 3.

The test command (which is aliased with square brackets ) returns 0 if code is successful `[ -e /etc/passwd ]` .

So in the sense it's the same as in C and Java, but reversed.

Corrected script

```
#!/bin/mksh
#set -x
echo "Start!"

while IFS=  read entry; do

  if [ -e "$entry" ] ; then

  echo "$entry exist"

   else

   echo "$entry doesnt exist"

   fi

done < $HOME/pathlist.txt
```

Also, don't code before you have coffee

Comment: The result is still the same.  I deleted abc.txt .  Output shows "abc.txt exists".

Comment: Huh ? That's strange . . . I'm 100% sure the syntax is correct. OK, I'll try to fix it

Comment: I will try running on Solaris machine - I am using CSH

Comment: `csh` syntax is different that `ksh` syntax. Also, if you specify to use `ksh` in the `#!/bin/ksh` it's ran by `ksh` , `csh` has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to learn how redirection in Unix is work. Because you need to use redirection when you invoke the script, but not in code.
2. I'm not sure, but I think you need replace `#!/bin/ksh` with `#!/bin/sh`.
3. PROFIT!

```
#!/bin/sh
while read entry; do
    if [ -s $entry ];
    then
        echo "$entry exists"
    else
        echo "$entry does not exist..."
fi
done
```

Save it and then.

```
chmod +x example2.sh
example2.sh < something/pathlist.txt
```

Comment: I ran echo $shell

    /bin/csh

script still not cooperating ._.

Comment: Works fine on bash.